# Java Generics compile error

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I don't understand why the compiler doesn't accept this code

```
import javax.swing.event.EventListenerList;

import java.util.EventListener;


public class GenericEventsManager {

   EventListenerList listeners = new EventListenerList();


   public <T extends EventListener> void addListener(T listener) {
      listeners.add(listener.getClass(), listener);
   }
}
```

The error I get is

```
The method add(Class<T>, T) in the type EventListenerList is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#1-of ? extends EventListener>, T)
```

The argument in addListener is of a type that extends EventListener, so listener.getClass() returns `Class<? extends EventListener>`, which is exactly what the EventListenerList.add method expects

Can someone explain this? I have a feeling that it has something to do with getClass() not being resolved at compile time but it still doesn't make sense to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Generic parameters without wildcards are not variant and therefore require exactly the same types (not sub-types, not super types). ([source](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=222021))

The compiler simply will not let you do this. As the error message implies, the type parameter on the `Class` parameter must be **exactly** the same as the type of the second argument, which is not true in the code above.

---

> How can they not be identical?

Because the return type of `listener.getClass()` is `Class<? extends EventListener>`, not `Class<T>`. You could — but I do **not recommend doing so** — cast the returned `Class` to make this compile:

```
listeners.add((Class<T>)listener.getClass(), listener);
```

You'll get a compiler warning when doing so:

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from Class<capture#1-of ? extends EventListener> to Class<T>
```

because this is **not a (type)safe cast.**

---

The root cause of this might (I'm honestly not sure) be simply poor API design in the declaration of `EventListenerList#add()`. Typically [PECS is used in this kind of situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs); it's possible there's a good reason that `add()` is not wildcarded.

Comment: How can they not be identical?

Comment: I see. Why can't the compiler go one step further and figure out that T **is** "? extends EventListener"?

Comment: Because that's not how `Object#getClass()` is declared. Note that you cannot write `Class<T> clazz = listener.getClass();` or `Class<EventListener> clazz = listener.getClass();` because those will also not compile.

Comment: Read this closely for another example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes but in your add method you are specifying a `Class<T>`, not a `Class<EventListener>`